What is the part of speech of "add" in "one add four equals five"?

My daughter is learning math in English (her teacher is British) and the above picture is from her book.
If they said "One plus four is five", I would not ask this question. That is because "plus" is a preposition and
"Plus" is a preposition. So, "One plus four is five" has the structure "Noun + prep + Noun + Verb + Noun".
I am not sure if "add" is a preposition.
If "add" is a verb, then that sentence "one add four equals five" doe snot make any sense.
I suspect "add" here is a preposition. But most dictionaries say "add" is a verb.

I would call it a verb. Compare: "Six take away 2 = 4".  Why doesn't it make sense? It could be imperative. Or an ellipted conditional.

@TimR, do you say "I go home cooks dinner"???

I read it as a conjunction. But I would also say '1 add 4' doesn't sound idiomatic to my ears.

Gin, add some dry vermouth and an olive, shake, don't stir.

It sounds like an imperative verb, which makes the sentence sound rather technical, like an algorithm in programming rather than a natural English phrase.

@Tom I don't get your point.

@LukeSawczak OP's visual aid is indeed an algorithmic (step-by-step) depiction of the process of addition.  Addition is a simple process, but it does have steps.

What is times in "four times four equals sixteen"?

Related: How to read "1 + (-2) = -1" and "1 - 2 = -1" and How do you read these mathematical expressions aloud?

There, the guy is telling the kids to perform addition. Normally, we just say plus there.

@ishtar There's no reason that it cannot be a verb instructing kids to add what is in the boxes!

The purpose of the diagram is to show kids what the sign means. When there is a (+) plus sign add.

I'm not sure why the OP believes one add four equals five is not syntactically acceptable.

it's simple. The book is wrong. I asked the teacher assistant about it and she said she would tell that to the the curriculum's manager @Tom 9 hours ago

I googled the following: 250 add 255 and Google gave me the answer, 505. Note how the equals sign (equal sign US) is highlighted in blue

I also did a subtraction: 250 take away 255  and Google's calculator said the answer was -5 (it used to be minus 5, but today we say  negative 5).  It also gave me the correct answers for 250 plus 250 and  250 minus 255. Consequently, it appears Google understands the simple mathematical  commands add, plus, minus and take away.

So what to say about the sum explained in simple words  on the children's book? It's not a command to number 1 to add itself to number 4. It's neither a full sentence as there is no obvious subject, so its probably an imperative clause, where add is a verb
Cambridge Dictionary

We use imperative clauses when we want to tell someone to do something (most commonly for advice, suggestions, requests, commands, orders or instructions).
We can use them to tell people to do or not to do things. They usually don’t have a subject – they are addressed to the listener or listeners, who the speaker understands to be the subject. We use the base form of the verb:
Have fun.
Enjoy your meal.
Stop talking and open your books.
Don’t be late.




If they said "One plus four is five", I would not ask this question.

In this exercise, the book wants to teach mathematical words to the kids and not a sentence. There is a speaker symbol under the word, which means the kid should be able to pronounce each word.
In this exercise each word would be taught seperately and not as a sentence.
While teaching, the teacher will show each figure and ask the kids "What is this? Count the circles ONE. What is this? ADD,  Then FOUR How many circles? Count them.

One
Add (symbol)
Four
Equals (symbol)
Five.

The teacher might in the end say.
"One added to four equals to five.

Reference liveworksheet.com



Also there's no capital letter at the start and no punctuation.

"add" is not a name, not a noun.

@TimR "add" is short for addition or plus sign.

It is very common for children in elementary school to say additions and multiplications and subtractions.    These are not merely symbols or abbreviations but have syntactic relationships

If "equals" is a noun, why did he add "s" to "equal", he means "equals" a verb. Also, "Addition" is a noun, "add" is a verb not a noun

@Tom Do you still believe that it is a sentence below the figures? Like StuartF commented where is the capital letter at start. In Maths children are taught to say - One plus (here add to make kids understand it is addition) four equals five. There is no English grammar in this.I think there may be  other figures in the book showing substraction, division, multiplication. The aim is to teach what the (+, -, x, ÷) signs mean.

@Tom While teaching will show and ask the kids "What is this? Count the circles ONE. What is this? ADD,  Then FOUR How many circles? Count them.

I said "noun" in the sense that when you name something with a verb, adjective etc, it becomes a noun (name of the figure)

@JamesMathai, it's simple. The book is wrong. I asked the teacher assistant about it and she said she would tell that to the the curriculum's manager

@Tom Perhaps the teacher assistant believes in the saying, "The parent is always right." I have attached a similar worksheet from the net and coincidentally it is in Vietnamese. This is a common method to teach mathematical words and signs in India too.

The diagram is not intended to be treated as a sentence. It's simply showing what each symbol in the equation represents as a mathematical concept, and the latter is expressed in English. But since equations aren't sentences, you shouldn't expect the translation to be a sentence, either.
It is possible to use different names for the symbols so that you get a sentence. If you call the + symbol "plus", you get

one plus four equals five

But this application has chosen to emphasize the action you do when you're performing math. "Add" is a verb that refers to the process of combining numerical values.
If you were expressing this in English you could say something like

Add one and four to get five.


addition, subtraction, division, multiplication: Usage, usage, usage
How do we talk about those?.
Like this:
1 plus 5 equals 6
5 minus 4 equals 1
8 divided by 2 equals 4
2 times 4 equals 8
+ in math is a sign. And we say plus by convention. In fact, the formal term for it is: a plus sign. The others signs are: the minus sign (-), the multiplication sign (x) and the division sign (÷).
Adding (addition)
If you add [verb] 2 plus 2 you get: 4
To use add (add is always a verb), you need two numbers if demonstrating an addition problem.
What matters is what people actually say, not the grammar of the word plus.
